# Font awesome icon works in Chrome but not Firefox?

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, firefox, font-awesome

foxfundraising.com  - uses frame redirect to display foxfundraising.foxdjmc.com - hosted on 1&1

I've already modified the

```
.htaccess
```

file with

```
<FilesMatch ".(eot|ttf|otf|woff)">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>
```

Still doesn't display the icon in FF. Works great in Chrome. I'm pulling my hair out because this solution works for everyone but me!

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you add those headers only on `foxfundraising.foxdjmc.com` or also on `foxdjmc.com`?  The latter is what the site is actually linking to, right?

Comment: Thanks. I feel dumb now haha. Feel free to post this as the answer since it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to add those headers on `foxdjmc.com` as well, since that's what the page links to.